# Return a classes load method using OOP

Tags: php

So I'm using the following output method to output a file called profile-card.php inside my template directory.

```
public function output()
{
    ob_start();
    $profile = $this;
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/mu-plugins/s/templates/profile-card.php';
    $output = ob_get_clean();

    return $output;
}
```

So instead of having that method output all that code, I want to convert is to something like this where I can just call a string on the filename and it will render the template:

```
public function output()
{
   return Template::load($this, 'profile-card');
}
```

What would be a good start/approach to tackle this? I have my Template::load() method setup with the following:

```
class Template
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        // @todo: Initialize the object's methods
    }

    public static function init()
    {
        // @todo: Build out the template from the directory
    }

    public static function load()
    {
       // @todo: Add in more code in here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a simple method taking a path and an array of parameters to pass to your view:

```
class Template
{
  private const PATH_FROM_DOCUMENT_ROOT = '/wp-content/mu-plugins/s/templates';

  public static function show(string $path, array $params = []): string
  {
    ob_start();
    extract($params, EXTR_OVERWRITE);
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . self::PATH_FROM_DOCUMENT_ROOT . $path . '.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Template::show('profile-card', ['profile' => $profile]);
//                                               ^ $this, in your case
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/NEt4r** (non-working there for obvious reasons, but shows a full sample)

Note: using a static method for this is probably not the greatest idea (I'd go as far as say it's to be avoided in general, but that's another discussion). I've kept this sample very basic to give you the general idea.

Comment: Wow, this gives great insight and guidance and it actually works! I'll do some tweaking, but thanks a bunch - Now I have something to work off of.

Comment: if I wanted to use it as `Template::show('profile-card', $profile);` without defining `'profile' =>`, which approach would I need to take?

Comment: @SLE You can make use of [`compact`](http://php.net/compact) for a shorter version: `Template::show('profile-card', compact('profile'));`. The advantage of taking an array of parameters is that it's a lot more flexible; `Template` doesn't have to know about profiles and simply transfers any passed parameters to the view.

Comment: However, if `$profile` *must* be a special value and templates *should* know about them, you could 1) pass it into the `Template` constructor, change the `show` method to non-static and have `$profile = $this->profile` before including the view file, or 2) have a dedicated `Profile $profile` parameter in `show` (`show(string $path, Profile $profile, array $params = [])`) and then use it with `Template::show('profile-card', $profile, compact('otherParam1', 'otherParam2'));`. I'd recommend 1.