# Unable to use load method to call multiple class getters and setters

Tags: php, class

I have three classes, which are Profile, Dish & Template. Profile grabs all the custom post type profiles, the Dish grabs all the custom post type dishes and my Template class is used as a "middle man" for both to render templates.

**Template (Class)**:

```
public static function load($profile, $path)
{
    ob_start();
    require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . Template::PATH_FROM_DOCUMENT_ROOT . '/' . $path . '.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

**Both output methods in each (Profile, Dish) class is defined as such**:

```
public function output()
{
    return Template::load($this, 'dish-gallery'); // dish-gallery/profile-card
}
```

There are two template files called: `dish-gallery.php` & `profile-card.php` - Inside my `profile-card.php`, I'm able to call the getters and setters using `$profile->` as shown below:
[image]

When I attempt to call `$dish->` inside my dish template, I can't target it at all:
[image]

Here is the link to the three full classes: https://paiza.io/projects/ssyYbkspBjLgXd8RBTg9Rw - I believe my issue has to do with the $profile parameter inside the load method, `var_dump(Template::load($this, 'dish-gallery'))` returns both templates perfectly, **the problem that I'm having is that I can't call my Dish getters and setters.**

**Former question that has helped me pave the way**: [Return a classes load method using OOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59923831/return-a-classes-load-method-using-oop)

Comment: Did you setup instances of `$profile` and `$dish` ?  No instance == no variable, hence your error message.

Comment: @Nic3500, within the paiza link that I provided, I have a init method for both - but I'm able to target $profile only without defining a new instance inside the file.

Comment: @SLE your `init` method is  **static** in `Dish` class but you haven't used static init method in `Profile` class.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal, good catch - I did some testing and seems like it's still not instanced - So I have some tweaking to do.

Comment: If your **$profile** is working correctly then **$dish** must also be worked. So make sure you have load the **Dish** class perfectly. and when you solved your problem then please inform here what' the problem ?

Comment: @AbhishekKamal, inside the Template class, as soon as I change the $profile parameter to $dish, now dish works and $profile doesn't - I'll have to see why.

Comment: yess It is class loading problem as I said.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal, looks like if I call `$profile->` inside my dish template, I'll target the correct "custom post type" which is my getters inside my template because of the output method.

Comment: So you have code designing issues... and make sure you're cleaning your buffer when you call **load** method in `Template` class second time.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal, true, will have to change it to a more general variable.